# Run an agent using LaunchAgent on Mac

Tags: macos

We have developed an application similar to anti-virus that has both background process as well as a GUI for user to interact with (note: the background process will be executed by the GUI as a separate thread).

The following are requirements for our application at deployment time on macOS:

1. The GUI part of the application should be launched using LaunchAgent for every user that log in. Even those users that their account is created after the installation of the software.
2. Users without admin privilege should not be able to stop GUI process by any means (e.g., launchctl unload/bootout or Activity Monitor)

**What we have done so far**

We have created a `plist` file in `/Library/LaunchAgents` and have loaded it using `launchctl load -F com.myfile.plist`, which loads successfully and since the scope is set to Aqua, any time the user loges in the agent gets started.

**Problems we have faced**

- Non-admin users can stop the loaded agent after logging in using `launchctl`

**Notes**

- We understand that we could put our application into "login items" of every user. We do not like this solution as we have to perform this task for every user, and if a new user is created after our installation, he/she won't automatically have our app in their login-items. Moreover, users seems to have access and able remove applications from their login-items list.
- The application has a GUI, thus we cannot launch it as a headless daemon. It's a JavaFX application and it uses many Swing calls, therefore it must have access to Aqua sessions.

Any idea on how we can meet our requirements of deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put the plist for the GUI in /Library/LaunchAgents and ADD the KeepAlive Key to the plist file. And the Background non GUI part in LaunchDaemons also with the KeepAlive Key.

So every User could end the process over ActivityMonitor but it would instantly relaunch after ended.

Only Admin Users would be able to End the process by running "sudo launchctl unload com.myfile.plist" or "sudo launchctl unload -w com.myfile.plist" disable it permanently.